# Grails onLoading events doesn't work

Tags: javascript, grails, onload

I am using a grails submit remote form. I want to use the onLoading event but it doesn't do anything. What could be the problem? The code is the same as in the documentation...

```
<g:formRemote dojoType="dijit.form.Form" method="post" onLoading="myFunction()" id="submitForm" update="resultset" name="formRemote" url="[ controller: 'controller', action:'index' ]">

myFunction = function() {
      alert("test 123 test");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying `doesn't do anything`? According to grails docs:
`onLoading (optional) - The JavaScript function to call when the remote function loads the response`
So it calls function when you submit form and wait for response.

Comment: Yes that is correct and I am aware of that but in my case when the response is being loaded my function does't get called. As if it was not working...

Comment: Unfortunately that works for me. Maybe `dojoType="dijit.form.Form"` is causing issues or controller does not give any response or specified element is missing?

Comment: Will try to remove this

Comment: heres my gist example: https://gist.github.com/aprudnikovas/5899280

Comment: I've almost copied your example but it still doesn't work. Thank for the help anyway...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32669/discussion-between-jacob-and-ivarprudnikov)